# JavaEEにおいて、JPAのfindメソッドで発生するエラー

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa

wildFly(Ver.8.2.0.Final)上で、JPAのecipselink(Ver.2.5.1)を用いたデータアクセスの動作確認をしています。

```
@Stateful(name = "PersonalInformationDaoBeanEJB")
public class PersonalInformationDaoBean implements Serializable {

private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
private EntityManager entityManager;

public PersonalInformationDaoBean() {
}

public void connect() {
    this.entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnit");
    this.entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

public Object loadSingleData(Class entityClass, int primaryKey) {
    try {
        return entityManager.find(entityClass, primaryKey);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

このクラスのメソッドを各々呼び出すことで、
EntityManagerFactoryとEntityManagerの作成とDBへのデータ取得を行いたいのですが、
JPAフレームワークのfindメソッドを呼ぶ際に、以下のような2つのExceptionが無作為に発生します。

```
・org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: スキーマ "SAMPLE" が見つかりません。
・Unknown entity bean class: class Entity.PersonalInformationEntity, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
```

ちなみに、persistence.xmlにスキーマ情報、PersonalInformationEntityには@Entityを付加しています。
このことから、他に原因があると考えられますが、現状特定することができていません。
どのような原因が考えられるのでしょうか？

また、以下にデータベースに対応するpersistence.xmlを載せます。
データベースはpostgreSQLを使用し、取得対象のカラムはデータベースに作成済です。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0"
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Entity.PersonalInformationEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="dummyUser"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="dummyPass"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: 変数名等を出したくない場合はダミー化なりして`PersonalInformationEntity`クラスのコードも示した方が良いと思います。

Comment: 確かにそうですね。
今後の参考にさせて頂きます。

Comment: PostgreSQLを使用しようとしているように見えますが、例外はH2のドライバが投げていますよね。今回の件と関係あるか確証はないのですが、Wildflyのどこかのバージョンで、デフォルトのH2データソース設定(ExampleDS)を削除すると問題が出ていた記憶があります。もしこの設定を削除/編集されているようであれば、一度元に戻して動作させてみるとどうなるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

persistence.xmlのプロパティを

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="dummyUser"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="dummyPass"/>
```

に変更した所、Exceptionが

```
javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
```

に変化したため、Webで検索してみた所、[JBossDeveloper](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/227944)にトランザクションタイプが"RESOURCE_LOCAL"でないと使えない旨の記述があったので、
persistence-unitの末尾にtransaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"を追記した結果、
主キーに一致するentityを取得することができるようになりました。